# How to access private apigateway endpoints in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc

I followed the following steps to create a vpc endpoint and attach it to the resource policy of the private api gateway endpoint:

1. Create a VPC endpoint

```
this.vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, props.stageName+'VPC');
this.vpcEndpoint = new ec2.InterfaceVpcEndpoint(this, 'ApiGatewayVpcEndpoint', {
    service: InterfaceVpcEndpointAwsService.APIGATEWAY,
    vpc: this.vpc,
    privateDnsEnabled: true,
});
```

2. Update the resource policy of the API gateway and attach the vpce id

```
  {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                    "Effect": "Deny",
                    "Principal": {
                        "AWS": "*"
                    },
                    "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                    "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:1234567891:abcdef/",
                    "Condition": {
                        "StringNotEquals": {
                        "aws:sourceVpce": "vpce-1234567890"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1234567891:root"
                    },
                    "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
                    "Resource": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:1234567891:abcdef/*"
             }
        ]
    }
```

3. Use the vpc endpoint public dns name to call the api gateway endpoint. Eg: `https://vpce-12345678901234-9ewcakgy-us-east-1a.execute-api.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com/test` Getting `port 443 failed: Operation timed out` error.

Is there any other steps involved in order to access the private api?

I followed instructions from [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html) doc.

Comment: Where are you calling this API endpoint from?

Comment: From another public api gateway

Comment: You can't call private api from a public api gateway.

Comment: I am using a vpc endpoint public dns name to call the private api gateway endpoint through the public api gateway. Based on what I read so far, public dns vpc endpoints can be used to call the private gatway.
If thats not the case, can you tell me what would be the right way to call those private endpoints?

Comment: The caller needs to be inside the same VPC to reach the private endpoint.